# Use \u as part of NSString

Tags: ios, xcode

i have link with \u in \uploads , it consider it as special character 
how can i solve this problem

```
 NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:\\www.school-link.net\uploads\%@",image_url];
```

Error is

\u used with no following hex digits xcode

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:\\www.school-link.net\\\uploads\%@",image_url];
```

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the backslash using "\\u"

Answer (score 0):

URLs have forward slashes (`/`) not back slashes (`\`). This is probably what you want:

```
NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.school-link.net/uploads/%@", image_url];
```